# Returning a pointer from a c++ function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return-value

I am trying to return an array of floats in the following function:

```
static GLfloat *LoadFile(const char *filePath) {
std::ifstream f;
f.open(filePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(!f.is_open()){
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to open file: ") + filePath);
}

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << f.rdbuf();

std::string s = buffer.str();
std::string delimiter = ",";

size_t pos = 0;
std::string token;

pos = s.find(delimiter);
token = s.substr(0, pos);
int numberOfItems = ::atof(token.c_str());
s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

pos = s.find(delimiter);
token = s.substr(0, pos);
int componentsPerItem = ::atof(token.c_str());
s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

int dataLength = numberOfItems * componentsPerItem;

GLfloat *data = new GLfloat[dataLength + 2];
data[0] = numberOfItems;
data[1] = componentsPerItem;

int counter = 2;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    GLfloat num = ::atof(token.c_str());
    if (counter > dataLength + 1)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Error in vertex data file: ") + filePath);
    data[counter] = num;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    counter++;
}
return data;
```

}

But when I set a variable equal to the return value:

```
GLfloat *data = LoadData();
```

data is equal to NULL. I was under the impression that because I used the new operator the value would be retained even after I left the scope of the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the function declaration as well?

Comment: I added the rest of the function @leonid

Comment: @hmjd Its not that I am trying to access a value that is out of bounds because if I output a random value inside the function I can. But if I try and do the same thing outside I get a memory read failed error

Comment: @hmjd If counter > dataLength + 1 then a runtime error is thrown. No error is thrown when I run the code.